# How can I get rid of the brackets used to initalize my array?

Tags: arrays, c, syntax

I have to create a program in C that asks for the user to input 80 or fewer characters and then alphabetize them using two functions outside of the `main()`. (for example "d c b a" would turn into "a b c d"). I also can't use any square brackets with my arrays or anywhere in my code. I managed to get rid of all brackets except initializing the array and the sorting function. I can't figure out how to do that.

This is some of the code from the main:

```
char *str[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Enter single character %d: ", i+1);
    str[i] = (char*)malloc(size);
    scanf(" %c", *(str+i));
}
sort(str, size);
```

And this is my function for sorting:

```
void sort(char *str[], int size) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
         if (strcmp(str[i], str[j]) > 0) {
            swap(str[i],str[j]);
         }
   }
}
```

I tried:

```
char *str=(char*)malloc(80*sizeof(char));
```

But I got errors with the various `*(str+i)` throughout my code and `sort(str, size);`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to sort a single *string* of user input characters (i.e., `"bdca"` -> `"abcd"`), or multiple *strings* (i.e., `{ "dog", "cat" }` -> `{ "cat", "dog" }`)? Your example is incomplete enough that it is hard to tell. Please try to post a [mre].

Comment: @Oka The user will input a single string and then it will be sorted alphabetically. Sorry, it's my first time posting here and I wasn't sure what was enough code or too much detail!

Comment: Your sorting function sorts an array of strings, though, hence the confusion.

Comment: Do not forget to account for the NUL byte at the end of a C string.

Comment: Do you have to write your own sorting function, or can you just lean on `qsort()`?

Comment: Rather than putting "solved" in the title, you should [accept an asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression that the purpose of this assignment is to get very familiar with pointers and the incrementing and decrementing of pointers in lieu of utilizing fairly conventional coding with array indices.

With that in mind, and reviewing your initial coding here is some refactored code to use as food for thought.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sortStrg(char *text)
{
    int swap = 0;
    char temp1, temp2, temp3, *work;

    while(1)
    {
        work = text;
        for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(text) - 1); i++)    /* Very crude and repetitive bubble sort - checking two adjancent characters at a time */
        {
            temp1 = *work;                              /* Increment and decrement the character pointer to work through the memory locations  */
            work++;
            temp2 = *work;
            if (temp1 > temp2)
            {
                temp3 = temp1;
                temp1 = temp2;
                temp2 = temp3;
                swap  = 1;
                //printf("Swapping occurs\n");
            }
            work--;
            *work = temp1;
            work++;
            *work = temp2;
        }

        if (swap == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            swap = 0;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    char *text,  *work;

    text = malloc(sizeof(char) * 81);

    printf("Enter some text: ");

    if(fgets(text, 80, stdin) == 0)
        return 1;

    work = text;

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)   /* Since fgets is being used, replace the possible newline character with a "0" terminator */
    {
        if (*work == '\n')
        {
            *work = '\0';
            break;
        }
        work++;
    }

    printf("This is what was entered: %s\n", text);

    sortStrg(text);

    printf("Sorted string: %s\n", text);

    free(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Following are some key points:

- Per the requirements, the character array (string) is defined via the definition of a character pointer and utilizing of the "malloc" function.
- Multiple character pointers are utilized that effectively reference the same block of memory for the character array.
- In lieu of referencing an array element (e.g. text[0]) navigation of the array is performed with incrementing and decrementing the pointer memory location.
- Sorting is performed utilizing a simple brute force bubble sort method.

Following is some test input and output at the terminal demonstrating the string sorting function.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SortString/bin/Release$ ./SortString 
Enter some text: euytopdghiiwpnnbs
This is what was entered: euytopdghiiwpnnbs
Sorted string: bdeghiinnoppstuwy
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SortString/bin/Release$ ./SortString 
Enter some text: dbca
This is what was entered: dbca
Sorted string: abcd
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SortString/bin/Release$ ./SortString 
Enter some text: d c b a
This is what was entered: d c b a
Sorted string:    abcd
```

It can be seen that characters are sorted in ascending order.  One thing to note is that in your narrative you gave an example of 'd c b a' would sort to be 'a b c d'.  This refactored iteration just considers a space as another character to be sorted.  If "space integrity" has to be considered, then there would need to be additional logic added for that.  However, this refactored code is just to provide a "proof of principle".

Along with your review of this code, it definitely would be advisable to review some tutorial literature that covers the usage and modification of pointers.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! I tried searching for how to do it and just got really confused. I really appreciate your explanation for everything! It's helped a lot

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider up-voting it. If it answers your question, consider accepting it. That's how to properly thank somebody for their time and effort. Simply saying you appreciate it, while doing neither of these things, is not a great way of showing appreciation. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @paddy I can't upvote yet because my account is too new. Sorry :( I just accepted it though! DIdn't realize that was a thing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort `char` values, then you should have an array of `char` values, not an array of pointers.

```c
char chars[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf(" %c", &(chars[i]));
}

sort(chars, size);
```

Also `char` values aren't compared using `strcmp`!

```c
void sort(char *chars, int size) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
         if (chars[i] > chars[j]) {
            swap(&(chars[i]), &(chars[j]));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With the underlying problems fixed, it should be easy to a different style of dereferencing (i.e. avoid using square brackets using the method already mentioned in the OP).

Answer (score 0):

> I also can't use any square brackets with my arrays or anywhere in my code.

If you can't, because of your "locale" (which is the only rationale that makes sense for avoiding `[]`), then you can use *digraphs* instead:

```c
char *str<:size:>;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Enter single character %d: ", i+1);
    str<:i:> = (char*)malloc(size);
    scanf(" %c", *(str+i));
}
sort(str, size);
```

As for avoiding `[]` because of academic nonsense requirements, then tell your teacher that the form `str[i]` is widely regarded as the most readable and that the equivalent form `*(str+i)` should be avoided. That is: assuming that the aim of the class is to learn how become good C programmers and not bad C programmers...